# Is this sentence grammatically correct - subject verb aggreement?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, verb-agreement

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

"The charge nurse would call the patient back from the waiting room and escort them to an empty exam room"

Call **the patient**... escort **them**??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"[Singular they](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they)" is considered correct by some, incorrect by others. The fact that this *them* is so close to its singular antecedent renders it more prominent and will probably draw extra attention from objecting pedants. The construction in general is used by many people, especially colloquially, but it is not universally accepted.